# avoiding/disabling lazy evaluation for pipeline processing

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

Imagine I have a set of functions for data processing, for example:

```
procA <- function(input){
  cat('\n Now processing #A') # message just to log pipeline flow 
  
  # Actual data processing, may include some diagnostic messaging:
  cat('\n #A: ', dim(input))
  input$procA <- 'procA'
  
  return(input)
}

procB <- function(input){
  cat('\n Now processing #B') # message just to log pipeline flow 
  
  # Actual data processing, may include some diagnostic messaging:
  cat('\n #B: ', dim(input))
  input$procB <- 'procB' 
  
  return(input)
}

procC <- function(input){
  cat('\n Now processing #C') # message just to log pipeline flow 
  
  # Actual data processing, may include some diagnostic messaging:
  cat('\n #C: ', dim(input))
  input$procC <- 'procC' 
  
  return(input)
}
```

And I combine them in a pipeline, for example:

```
data(iris)

iris_processed <-
  iris %>% 
  procA %>% 
  procB %>% 
  procC
```

Messaging output will be as following:

> Now processing #C
> Now processing #B
> Now processing #A
> #A:  150 5
> #B:  150 6
> #C:  150 7

Due to lazy evaluation, those log messages go in the opposite order which makes it harder for me to debug the pipeline. So far my solution is to add `input <- eval(input)` at the beginning of each function. Is there any better solution, any good practice standards, etc.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use the magrittr eager pipe.  Note that a `library(magrittr)` is needed. It is not sufficent to just use `library(dplyr)`.

```
library(magrittr)

iris_processed <-
  iris %!>% 
  procA %!>% 
  procB %!>% 
  procC

## Now processing #A
##  #A:  150 5
##  Now processing #B
##  #B:  150 6
##  Now processing #C
##  #C:  150 7>
```

Comment: You already answered this once :) I upvoted the dupe-target. Maybe consider adding this variant to the dupe-target. It can act as a canonical.

Comment: `%!>%` did not exist at the time of that question.

Comment: I agree, the answer with `%!>%` provided here is not included in the questions cited. Thanks @G.Grothendieck !

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I provided 3 dupe-targets (you provided an answer to all of those). You did update/edit those answers with different/newer solutions. What's keeping us from adding another solution to those, instead of posting yet another answer and scatter the info all over the place? In any case, you helped another soul. Thank you!

Comment: @VasilyA it is included: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850216 see solution(3).

Comment: I have answered literally thousands of questions and unless a question was answered recently I am not going to be able to remember that.